# Tensorflow GPU test code give error massage but tensorflow can insert

Tags: python, tensorflow

I installed Tensorflow GPU version with necessary Cuda software. Now I can import the tensorflow also without any errors.

```
import tensorflow
```

But when I tried to check GPU version it is giving an error message.

Test Code:

```
import tensorflow
# Creates a graph.
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
  a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
  b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b')
c = tf.matmul(a, b)
# Creates a session with log_device_placement set to True.
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
# Runs the op.
print(sess.run(c))
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-8-438712b7660b>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/iHacker/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/iHacker/.spyder-py3')

  File "C:\Users\iHacker\Anaconda3\envs\gpuenv\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 786, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\iHacker\Anaconda3\envs\gpuenv\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/iHacker/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 9, in <module>
    print(sess.run(c))

  File "C:\Users\iHacker\Anaconda3\envs\gpuenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 929, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)

  File "C:\Users\iHacker\Anaconda3\envs\gpuenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1152, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)

  File "C:\Users\iHacker\Anaconda3\envs\gpuenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1328, in _do_run
    run_metadata)

  File "C:\Users\iHacker\Anaconda3\envs\gpuenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1348, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)

InvalidArgumentError: Cannot assign a device for operation MatMul: Operation was explicitly assigned to /device:GPU:0 but available devices are [ /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 ]. Make sure the device specification refers to a valid device.
     [[node MatMul (defined at C:/Users/iHacker/.spyder-py3/temp.py:5)  = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false, _device="/device:GPU:0"](a, b)]]

Caused by op 'MatMul', defined at:
  File "C:\Users\iHacker\Anaconda3\envs\gpuenv\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\iHacker\Anaconda3\envs\gpuenv\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\iHacker\Anaconda3\envs\gpuenv\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\console\__main__.py", line 11, in <module>
    start.main()
  File "C:\Users\iHacker\Anaconda3\envs\gpuenv\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\console\start.py", line 310, in main
    kernel.start()
  File "C:\Users\iHacker\Anaconda3\envs\gpuenv\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 505, in start
    self.io_loop.start()
  File "C:\Users\iHacker\Anaconda3\envs\gpuenv\lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 132, in start
    self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
  File "C:\Users\iHacker\Anaconda3\envs\gpuenv\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 438, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "C:\Users\iHacker\Anaconda3\envs\gpuenv\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1451, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "C:\Users\iHacker\Anaconda3\envs\gpuenv\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 145, in _run
    self._callback(*self._args)
  File "C:\Users\iHacker\Anaconda3\envs\gpuenv\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 758, in _run_callback
    ret = callback()
  File "C:\Users\iHacker\Anaconda3\envs\gpuenv\lib\site-packages\tornado\stack_context.py", line 300, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\iHacker\Anaconda3\envs\gpuenv\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1233, in inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\iHacker\Anaconda3\envs\gpuenv\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1147, in run
    yielded = self.gen.send(value)
  File "C:\Users\iHacker\Anaconda3\envs\gpuenv\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 357, in process_one
    yield gen.maybe_future(dispatch(*args))
  File "C:\Users\iHacker\Anaconda3\envs\gpuenv\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 326, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "C:\Users\iHacker\Anaconda3\envs\gpuenv\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 267, in dispatch_shell
    yield gen.maybe_future(handler(stream, idents, msg))
  File "C:\Users\iHacker\Anaconda3\envs\gpuenv\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 326, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "C:\Users\iHacker\Anaconda3\envs\gpuenv\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 534, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin,
  File "C:\Users\iHacker\Anaconda3\envs\gpuenv\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 326, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "C:\Users\iHacker\Anaconda3\envs\gpuenv\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py", line 294, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "C:\Users\iHacker\Anaconda3\envs\gpuenv\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\zmqshell.py", line 536, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\iHacker\Anaconda3\envs\gpuenv\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2819, in run_cell
    raw_cell, store_history, silent, shell_futures)
  File "C:\Users\iHacker\Anaconda3\envs\gpuenv\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2845, in _run_cell
    return runner(coro)
  File "C:\Users\iHacker\Anaconda3\envs\gpuenv\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\async_helpers.py", line 67, in _pseudo_sync_runner
    coro.send(None)
  File "C:\Users\iHacker\Anaconda3\envs\gpuenv\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3020, in run_cell_async
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "C:\Users\iHacker\Anaconda3\envs\gpuenv\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3191, in run_ast_nodes
    if (yield from self.run_code(code, result)):
  File "C:\Users\iHacker\Anaconda3\envs\gpuenv\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3267, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-1-438712b7660b>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/iHacker/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/iHacker/.spyder-py3')
  File "C:\Users\iHacker\Anaconda3\envs\gpuenv\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 786, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\iHacker\Anaconda3\envs\gpuenv\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
  File "C:/Users/iHacker/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 5, in <module>
    c = tf.matmul(a, b)
  File "C:\Users\iHacker\Anaconda3\envs\gpuenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py", line 2057, in matmul
    a, b, transpose_a=transpose_a, transpose_b=transpose_b, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\iHacker\Anaconda3\envs\gpuenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_math_ops.py", line 4857, in mat_mul
    name=name)
  File "C:\Users\iHacker\Anaconda3\envs\gpuenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\iHacker\Anaconda3\envs\gpuenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py", line 488, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\iHacker\Anaconda3\envs\gpuenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3274, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\iHacker\Anaconda3\envs\gpuenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1770, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Cannot assign a device for operation MatMul: Operation was explicitly assigned to /device:GPU:0 but available devices are [ /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 ]. Make sure the device specification refers to a valid device.
     [[node MatMul (defined at C:/Users/iHacker/.spyder-py3/temp.py:5)  = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false, _device="/device:GPU:0"](a, b)]]
```

How to solve this problem?

Is it working fine of GPU version?

Comment: Does your GPU show when you run `tf.test.gpu_device_name()`? Which OS, tf version and graphics card/cuda version are you using? How did you install tf (conda, pip, compile from source ...)

Comment: when i use tf.test.gpu_device_name() conde i get ' ' only. I am using laters version with python 3.6. I am using Cuda 9. I install by pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow-gpu code